# Prove $|x|^2$ = $x^2$

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, absolute-value, square-numbers

My first attempt at this proof divided into 2 cases, one where $x^2$ is greater than or equal to 0, and another where $x^2$ is less than 0.

For the first case, I said that the definition of absolute value says that $|x|^2$ = $x^2$.

For the second case, I said that the definition of absolute value says that $|x|^2$ = $(-x)^2$ = $x^2$. I then concluded to say that since both cases were correct, the proof was completed.

This was marked incorrect by my instructor, and he marked that I was not considering $|x^2|$. I'm assuming by this that I used the absolute value definition to show that $|x^2|$ = $x^2$, which isn't the same thing as saying $|x|^2$ = $x^2$. Another thing he pointed out was that the case $x^2 < 0$ never happens, which I probably should have noticed the first time.

I feel like the proof should be shown by me showing that $x^2$ is always positive, but I don't know if I can outright say that without giving the formal definition of $x^2$. Another thing I wanted to try was to show that $|x|^2$ = $|x^2|$ through saying $|x|^2$ = $|x| * |x|$ and then using the theorem that $|xy|$ = $|x||y|$ to conclude that $|x| * |x|$ = $|x^2|$. But I think that would take me down the same route as last time, which would be marked incorrect.

Comment: Your "mistake" may simply be a typo. For the negative case you should have written $|x|^2=(-x)^2=x^2$. Somehow the absolute value sign wandered.

Comment: Whoops, that was actually a typo here. I didn't make that typo on the assignment. Just fixed it.

Comment: Oh, and I did not notice, in the first line the cases should be $x\ge 0$ and $x\lt 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cases to examine are (i) $x\ge 0$ and (ii) $x\lt 0$.

In Case (i), we have $|x|^2=x^2$.

In Case (ii), we have $|x|^2=(-x)^2=x^2$. Conceivably one might want to insert an extra step, $(-x)^2=(-1)^2x^2=x^2$.

Answer (score 7):

What is your definition of absolute value?

If your definition is ...

> $$|x| \;:=\; \sqrt{x^2}$$

... then the result is proven simply by squaring.

If your definition is ...

> $$|x|\;:=\;\begin{cases}\phantom{-}x, \;\text{for}\; x\geq 0 \\[4pt]
> -x, \;\text{for}\;x < 0\end{cases}$$

... then you can argue as @André did, or you could consider

$$|x|^2 - x^2 \;=\; \left(\;|x|-x\;\right)\left(\;|x|+x\;\right)$$

Whether $|x| = x$ or $|x| = -x$ (under *whatever* conditions), the product must vanish.